# Iterative Postorder Traversal of a Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal, postorder

I was attempting to solve the [Q145 on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-postorder-traversal/description/), which basically asks you to traverse a binary tree in a postorder method.

Writing the code using recursion posed no challenge, but the iterative method took some figuring out.

While I have a solution that I think works, LeetCode isn't accepting it as the error of "Memory Limit Exceeded" comes.

Is there any way to further simplify the solution I've come up with?

```
public static class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
}


//*******************************************


public List<Integer> postorderTraversalIterative (TreeNode root) {


        List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Stack <TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();

        TreeNode currentNode = root;
        int visited = 0;

        while (!stack.isEmpty() || currentNode!=null) {

            while (currentNode!=null) {
                stack.push(currentNode);
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            }

            currentNode = stack.pop();

            if (currentNode.right == null) {
                list.add(currentNode.val);
            }

            else {

                if (visited==0) {
                    stack.push(currentNode);
                    visited = 1;
                }

                else {
                    list.add(currentNode.val);
                    currentNode = null;
                    visited=0;
                }
            }

            if (currentNode!=null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
        }

        return list;
}
```

The bigger *else block* (and the variable *visited*) are basically there for ensuring that nodes that have a right child do get added to the *list*, once the right child has been traversed.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more suited for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work out for you? If not, please share my mistakes so that I can work on them.

```
public List<Integer> postorderTraversalIterative(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root == null) return result;

    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(root);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode node = stack.pop();
        result.add(0, node.val); // Add node value to the front of the list

        // Push left child first, then right child
        if (node.left != null) stack.push(node.left);
        if (node.right != null) stack.push(node.right);
    }

    return result;
}
```

For tree like this:

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
```

Result is:

```
[4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 1]
```